# Overriding Button styling with appcompat V21 theme

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm now using AppCompat.Theme but would like the buttons to not show up with the caption all capitalized as appears when running on a v21 device. Running on V18 or 19 the captions show up in mixed case as defined in my string definitions, but on 5.0 they're in all caps.

In general, I am able to style buttons -- such as with a custom background image -- by using a style without any specific inheritance. For example, here is my app's theme definition:

```
    <style name="GedStarThemeMisc" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_other_primary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_other_primary_dark</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_other_accent</item>
    </style>
```

And here is a typical style I apply to a Button widget in a layout:

```
    <style name="large_cust_btn">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:capitalize">words</item>
</style>
```

The "capitilize" item is my attempt to override the apparent v21 default. So how should I go about getting my specific button styling to work?

Comment: Your question is well elaborated. But it has been asked many times since L came out. All caps for buttons is L default behavoir

Comment: I see that now. I searched but apparently wasn't creative enough with my search terms.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```

in your button style.

Comment: Doesn't work if you have support for API 10

Comment: Should be fixed in API22, using  `<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>` without the android prefix.

Comment: Thankfully we are removing API 10 soon!